# REST URI design: Resource with plural name

Tags: rest, uri, api-design

I have a collections of customers and each customer has a `relationships` resource that looks like this:

```
{
  "customerId" : "string",
  "accounts" : [{
    "accountId" : "string",
     ...
  }],
  "profiles" : [{
    "profileId" : "string",
     ...
  }]
}
```

I am building a REST api to provide access to this resource and sub resources like `accounts` and `profiles`.

This is the URIs that I came up with:

1. /customers/{id}/relationships  - To return the above resource
2. /customers/{id}/relationships/accounts - To return `accounts` sub resource
3. /customers/{id}/relationships/profiles - To return `profiles` sub resource

But one issue I see is that `relationships` resource looks like a collection. So it will be expected to have a `{relationshipId}` after that. But actually it is a single resource. How can I design URIs for this?

Comment: For clarity, relationships is a single object containing multiple types of relationship?
If so why does relationships exist? couldn't you do /customers/{id}/accounts and /customers/{id}/profiles and get around the issue entirely?

Comment: Mainly because /customers/{id} resource is not available for us to make changes. Also there are requirements where we need to return both accounts and profiles relationships together. Thats why we have a parent /relationships resource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If 'relationships' is a single object and not a collection you could go several ways.

1. Remove it entirely so you have /customers/{id}/accounts and /customers/{id}/profiles
2. Rename it to something else /customers/{id}/**related**/accounts
3. Leave it as is... This still works as 'accounts' and 'profiles' become id's beneath the relationships collection (/customers/{id}/relationships/{id(accounts|profiles)}

It is always good to follow standards. But often you can spend too long worrying about minor issues in which ultimately no matter which way you go, will not make a massive difference.

Comment: The /customer/{id} resource is not available to us to modify. Also we have requirement where we need to return both accounts and profile relationships together. So a parent resource is necessary.

Comment: If you *could* modify the /customer/{id} resource you could satisfy your requirement by simply returning both accounts and profile relationships in your customer object. Unfortunately, if you can't modify it this doesn't help you. But neither of these problems prevent you from going with option 2 or 3?

Comment: Thanks @Leigh for the comments. Finally we decided to go with 2nd option.

Answer (score 0):

You need to decide if relationships is a document or a collection. See this for definitions:

https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/

If you think it is a collection then `/customers/{id}/relationships/accounts` is correct where `accounts` is an id of the resource in collection.

If you think of it as a document then you are requesting a limited view of the document and you can use something like `/customers/{id}/relationships?$select=accounts` if you wish to follow it the OData way

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/using-select-expand-and-value#using-select